# What is this decorative plant with small white flowers that blossoms in mid-May?

Tags: identification

This is a decorative shrub that grows on the alleys and streets of my town in Moscow region, Russia. It blossoms in the middle of May, with the day temperature around 20 °C.

It's not hortensia, jasmine or lilac, which are common as street decorative plants around here. On ShootGardening, I found the [Silver ghost rose](https://www.shootgardening.co.uk/plant/rosa-silver-ghost), with the flowers looking similar, but larger than flowers in question.

[image: Shrub]

[image: Flowers]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is Spiraea arguta, common name Bridal Wreath, a hardy, deciduous flowering shrub. Further info and image here https://www.rhsplants.co.uk/plants/_/spiraea-arguta/classid.8041/

Comment: Just a warning: it could be invasive. It makes so many berries (red), which are very nice in winter, but birds will spread out everywhere.

Comment: Red berries on Spiraea? not so far as I know...

Comment: Right. I confused it often with an other plant (which naturally I do not remember the name [the thorny one]).